# Which abelian groups have only a single composition series?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

Cyclic groups of composite powers don't: for example, $1=C_1\triangleleft C_3\triangleleft C_6 $ and $1=C_1\triangleleft C_2\triangleleft C_6 $ are both composition series for $C_6$.

But cyclic groups of prime powers certainly do, because you'll just have $C_1\triangleleft C_p$.

Are there other cases of abelian groups with this property?

Comment: By "a single composition series," what exactly do you mean?  Subgroup-level uniqueness  (i.e., if $1=G_0 \triangleleft G_1 \triangleleft \ldots \triangleleft G_n=G$ and $1=H_0 \triangleleft H_1 \triangleleft \ldots \triangleleft H_n=G$ are two composition series, then $G_i=H_i$ for all $i$)?  Or, subgroup-level isomorphisms (i.e., if $1=G_0 \triangleleft G_1 \triangleleft \ldots \triangleleft G_n=G$ and $1=H_0 \triangleleft H_1 \triangleleft \ldots \triangleleft H_n=G$ are two composition series, then $G_i\cong H_i$ for all $i$)?

Comment: Subgroup-level uniqueness.

Comment: Then, only cyclic groups of order $p^k$, where $p$ is a (positive) prime integer and $k$ is a nonnegative integer, have this property.

Comment: If you want "subgroup-level isomorphisms," then either $G$ is a cyclic group of order $p^k$ or $G$ is the direct sum of $k$ copies of the cyclic group of order $p$.